# Как на WooCommerce под WordPress добавить Price возле цены

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно добавить надпись Price  рядом с ценой товара, "Price: $000", сейчас выводится просто цена "$000", как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте фильтр в function.php вашей темы

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $_this ) {
    return 'Price: ' . $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Но в этом случае не учитываются вариативные товары. При вариациях получается дублирование названия в обеих местах - там где показывается диапазон цен и там где происходит вывод цены товара. Как изменить название только для цены, не затрагивая диапазон? [![диапазон цен](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hco3S.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hco3S.jpg)

Comment: @Oleksandr в вопросе нет ни слова про вариации. Задайте другой вопрос.